# crear tabla de imágenes

Tags: php, html5, css3

Estoy creando un blog y tengo una página para colocar unas cuantas fotos.
Quiero poner tres fotos por fila y un pie de foto en cada una.
Mi duda es si puedo poner un footer en cada celda de la tabla o con una etiqueta < p> quedará bien.
Muchas gracias por adelantado.
Este es el código de la página:

```
<?php require('includes/config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fotos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/styles.css">
    <style>
        #seccion{
            background-color:#9BE8FF;
        }
        #seccion>h2{
            color:green;
        }
        footer{
            color:blue;
            font:15px bold;
            text-align:center;
            border-radius:25px;
            border:5px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>REAL ZARAGOZA</h1>    
        <h3>... MÁS QUE UNA PASIÓN!</h3>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">Sobre nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="fotos.php">Fotos</a></li>
            <li><a href="admin/add-user.php">Crear cuenta</a></li>
            <li><a href="admin/login.php">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <aside>
            <h1>ENLACES DE INTERES</h1>
            <a href="http://realzaragoza.com">Página oficial del Real Zaragoza</a></br>
            <a href="http://aupazaragoza.com">Página de Aupa Zaragoza</a></br>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/realzaragoza">Real Zaragoza en Twitter</a></br>
            <a href="https://es-es.facebook.com/RealZaragozaOficial">Real Zaragoza en Facebook</a></br>
            <a href="https://instagram.com/realzaragoza">Real Zaragoza en Instagram</a></br>
            <a href="https://heraldo.es/noticias/deportes/futbol/real_zaragoza/portada">Heraldo de Aragón</a></br>
            <a href="http://elperiodicodearagon.com/noticias/realzaragoza">El Periódico de Aragón</a></br>
            <h1>PATROCINADORES</h1>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://adidas.es" target="_blank"><img src="images/adidas.png" alt="ADIDAS" border="0"></a></br>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://jamoneseutiquio.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/eutiquio.jpg" alt="JAMONES EUTIQUIO" border="0"></a></br>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://caixabank.es/particular/home/particulares_es.html" target="_blank"><img src="images/caixabank.jpg" alt="CAIXABANK" border="0"></a></br>
            <a align="middle" class="foto" href="https://movistar.es" target="_blank"><img src="images/movistar.jpg" alt="MOVISTAR" border="0"></a></br>
        </aside>
        <section id="seccion">
            <h2>FOTOS DE LA ACTUALIDAD ZARAGOCISTA</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>© 2018 Charly Utrilla</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, muestra el código que tengas hasta el momento

Comment: tienes razón, he editado la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar las etiquetas [figure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/figure) y [figcaption](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/figcaption)

Ejemplo:

```
<figure>
  <img src="imagen.png" alt="Imagen" />
  <figcaption>Descripción</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, RockoDev. No sabía que existían esas etiquetas.